How can I use a span class to edit the text inside every span throughout a webpage with the same class at once
I'm working on a project that involves multiple sections of text, each reappearing in multiple places throughout a webpage. Because up to 37 different sections of text occasionally need to be updated, and each one of them will be repeated up to 11 times, I need to find a way to update the document more easily. I'm using spans because these are sentences that are inside paragraphs.
My thinking is if I use a span class, it will associate with each of the individual sections and I can repeat them where they appear throughout.
I assume what I would do is use JavaScript to update the text associated with that class, which would change the text on the site. I've looked at so many things and tried a lot and cannot figure out what this would be called.
Because this is a work project, I'm making up a scenario like a movie theater website that would like to update various parts of the site quickly. Here's a section of code that I tried but using this scenario.
I hope this makes sense, but this is what I tried. When I update the words like four, movies, tomorrow, popcorn, or $5.00, I would like it to update the corresponding text below by the span class. If anyone knows of a different method, that's fine. My goal is to have some sort of label (like a class) that I can use multiple times to update the text. I want the ability to update them to be in the code so no drop-down boxes or anything visible.
<!-- -----I want to update the words for each span class in the script so that when I have multiple places on the page with the same class, it will update all of the words in that class.  --------- -->

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var div = document.getElementsByClassname('NumberOfMoives');
span.innerHTML = four;

var div = document.getElementsByClassname('MoviePlural');
span.innerHTML = movies;

var div = document.getElementsByClassname('Day');
span.innerHTML = tomorrow;

var div = document.getElementsByClassname('Snack');
span.innerHTML = Popcorn;

var div = document.getElementsByClassname('SnackPrice');
span.innerHTML = $5.00;
}
</script>

<!-- -----I put the words inside the spans that I want to populate from above but in reality, I shouldn't have to add them as they would be empty spans that populate the words that I need when I update the script. --------- -->

<div>
The movie theater is featuring <span class= "NumberOfMoives">four</span> <span class= "MoviePlural">movies</span> <span class= "Day">tomorrow</span>. <span class= "Snack">Popcorn</span> will be sold at the concessions at <span class= "SnackPrice">$5.00</span>. Here is the list of the show times.
<br><br>
With <span class= "NumberOfMoives">four</span> different <span id= "MoviePlural">movies</span> to choose from, you can't turn it down.  We look forward to seeing you <span class= "Day">tomorrow</span>.
</div>


Typo?  Did you just forget to enclose your string values in quotes?  For example: span.innerHTML = 'four';

Any DOM functions with plurals in the name return a list not a single element eg: getElement Vs getElements.

Your code sets the variable div then assigns to span.innerHTML. Are they supposed to be the same variable?

Aside from the syntax issues with unquoted strings, which I'm assuming is an error in transposing your code in to the question, the main issue in your code is that you're selecting elements by class. This will return multiple elements, so you need to loop through them all to update their text individually.
You can fix this, and make the logic more extensible, by placing the content in an object, one key per set of text labels you'd like to apply. You can then use a single class on all the elements that need to have their text updated, with a data attribute on them to specify which property of the target object should be used to set their text.
Here's a working example, using a button to easily toggle the content:


// text label switching
const translateableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.translate');
const setText = key => {  
  translateableElements.forEach(el => el.textContent = content[key][el.dataset.prop]);
}

// demo content
const content = {
  'foo': {
    numberOfMovies: 'four',
    moviePlural: 'movies',
    day: 'tomorrow',
    snack: 'Popcorn',
    snackPrice: '$5.00'
  },
  'bar': {
    numberOfMovies: 'ten',
    moviePlural: 'movies',
    day: 'Friday',
    snack: 'Hotdogs',
    snackPrice: '$2.50'
  }
}

// demo button handler
document.querySelector('#toggle').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const key = e.target.dataset.key == 'foo' ? 'bar' : 'foo' 
  setText(key);
  e.target.dataset.key = key;
});
<button id="toggle" data-key="foo">Toggle text</button>

<div>
  The movie theater is featuring 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="numberOfMovies">four</span> 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="moviePlural">movies</span> 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="day">tomorrow</span>. 
  
  <span class="translate" data-prop="snack">Popcorn</span> 
  will be sold at the concessions at 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="snackPrice">$5.00</span>.
  
  Here is the list of the show times.<br><br> 
  With 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="numberOfMovies">four</span> 
  different 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="moviePlural">movies</span> 
  to choose from, you can't turn it down. We look forward to seeing you 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="day">tomorrow</span>.
</div>

<div>
  The movie theater is featuring 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="numberOfMovies">four</span> 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="moviePlural">movies</span> 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="day">tomorrow</span>. 
  
  <span class="translate" data-prop="snack">Popcorn</span> 
  will be sold at the concessions at 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="snackPrice">$5.00</span>.
  
  Here is the list of the show times.<br><br> 
  With 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="numberOfMovies">four</span> 
  different 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="moviePlural">movies</span> 
  to choose from, you can't turn it down. We look forward to seeing you 
  <span class="translate" data-prop="day">tomorrow</span>.
</div>




instead of using a button, is there a way I can just update the text as needed. THe updates the site/document will not be expected and I don't want a visible button to update anything.
From the user's view, it's just bodies of text; from the backend POI, I can just update the spans as needed. I just want to be able to update all the places where that sentence or word repeats on the page.

Absolutely. I just added the button for the sake of the demo, and your question wasn't clear about how the different texts would be applied. You can specify the keys (foo and bar in the example above) in any way you like.

from the backend POI, I can just update the spans as needed if this is the case, I'm confused why you need a client-side JS solution?

First, I want to say thank you for taking the time to help me. I appreciate it a lot. I think I'm confusing everyone in this post, mind you, I'm not the most skilled at coding, especially JavaScript.
I made a visual aid to make it easier to understand what I mean.
The image in this link is an example of what the webpage will look like.
https://imgur.com/MMKp1oF

The colored boxes represent areas that the text will change. The boxes with matching colors represent the same text that will change into another set, but regardless of what I change, these boxes will always match. So when I modify the code for the webpage, I need a table of code that represents those boxes. Text1, text2, text3, ect...
I just want to change text1 once in the code, so whatever I change in the code, it changes all of the text (colored boxes) at once. I don't know how to do this even after reviewing the code that you made with the button.

According to what I understood from your words, this may be useful to you:
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('NumberOfMoives');
spans.forEach((span)=> {
     span.innerHTML = 'four';
});


You might know what I'm talking about. I'm not sure how to write the HTML with the text to tell it to change the span to the word that's in the code you created. For the code below, I want the word "four" to appear in that span and all the other spans I make with the same How can I fix this code to work like that?


The movie theater is featuring 
